# How do I define a javascript function as a variable from a variable

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, aws-lambda

I'm trying to create a callback function in response to a JSONP request in Node.

I receive callbackName as a String, and I have an Object (lets say var obj = {a : "b"})
I need to return the following :

```
callbackName({a : "b"});
```

I tried concatenating strings - but I got

```
"callbackName([Object object])";
```

I tried JSON.Stringify but got:

```
"callbackName({\"a\":\"b"});"
```

which is close - but it's all stringy. Is there a way to get exactly what I want?

***UPDATE***

The code I'm using - which is in an AWS Lambda Function (turns out this is rather significant!)

```
    context.succeed(request.callback + "(" + JSON.stringify(obj) + ");");
```

As mentioned below - Lambda expects an Object in succeed, which it calls JSON.Stringify on.

Any ideas on how I could proceed?

Comment: I suspect the results of JSON.Stringify are exactly what you want, but you're looking at the value somewhere that expresses it as a JS string literal instead of plain text. You haven't shown us the code you are using, so it's hard to tell what is really wrong.

Comment: This is 2015 though. We have CORS now. JSONP should be allowed to wither and die.

Comment: It's possible to get out the data object and pass it through a variable in callback, but like @Quentin said, you must to show us your code.

Comment: JSONP response should be parsed by browser and executed. Show your code for request.

Comment: Think I've found the issue - the response is in a AWS Lambda function - which I believe re-wraps the response in another JSON.Stringify. So I'd need a real function call for it to stringify??? Now it's getting complicated. Also - if retards in large companies would stop using IE9, I'd stop using JSONP

Comment: @Andrey — The code for the request doesn't matter. What matters is the code that generates the response and what the response actually looks like.

Comment: Could you post here the code you are trying?

Comment: There are a lot of ways to implementing a JSONP response. I suggest you to look at how widely used microframeworks like [Express](http://expressjs.com/) have [implemented it](https://github.com/strongloop/express/blob/master/lib/response.js#L264)

Comment: A lot of good security checks in that Express code - but at the end of the day - they also just return callback + '(' + body + ')' - my problem is that this gets stringified again....

Comment: Do you know beforehand the names of all callbacks and their bodies?

Comment: @Silver and it's correct. As Andrey point out, the response _has_ to be a string and should be parsed by the browser.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, then you need something like this:

```
var obj = {a:"b"};
var callbackName = "callback";

var scope = {};

scope.callback = function(e) {
    return function() {
        console.log(e);
    }
}

setTimeout( scope[callbackName](obj), 1000 );
```